# Bootstrap 3 nav next to floated element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with Bootstrap 3. The setup is a simple 2-column page (sidebar and main content). Because I have dropdown menus which can overlay out of the main container, I cannot use the visibility:hidden or auto trick.

I use another technique which is applying a padding-left to the main container to ignore the floated element.

```
.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.main {
    padding-left: 210px;
}
```

Unfortunately, bootstrap navs use a clearfix internally which causes the navbar inside main to become as big as the sidebar.

http://jsfiddle.net/9ejqa/1/

Is there a way to make the clear only clear elements inside main and not including the sidebar?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific??

Comment: Why are you customizing the elements? Just use the regular Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/blog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of manually trying to make the columns yourself you can use the built-in bootstrap classes that do everything for you and are responsive.

First wrap everything with a div that has `class="container"`and in that you have a div with `class="row"` then add to the sidebar and to the main div the appropriate `col` class'

Use the bootstrap Grid page as a [reference](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to see all the examples they have.

I have updated your [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ejqa/5/) with the basic markup to do what you need, hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback!

Unfortunately, the website has been designed without bootstrap and the sidebar isn't intended to be variable width (must be 200px)

Altough your solution is what we want to achieve in the future, I think I might have a short-term solution, which I don't really like because of the absolute positioning.
http://jsfiddle.net/9ejqa/6/

Comment: @guillaumesmo Yeah I think that would be the only way to achieve this without adding the Grids Bootstrap layout to the structure.